# Should my IEnumerable enumerate IEnumerable which is passed as a parameter to method like AddRange()?

Tags: c#

My class implements `IEnumerable<T>`. Class also implements:

```
void AddRange(IEnumerable<T> items) 
{
    // items can be a deffered query against the collection items being added to
    var itemslist = items.ToList();
    ...processing and adding...
}
```

But I have some doubts *whether convertion to a static collection is a good design*.

For example List itself has nothing like this:

```
var list = new List<int> {1, 2, 3};
list.AddRange(list.Select(i => i+list.Count).ToList());
```

No exception.

```
var list = new List<int> {1, 2, 3};
list.AddRange(list.Select(i => i+list.Count));
```

InvalidOperationException : collection was modified during enumeration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`List<T>.AddRange` will behave differently depending on whether the sequence it's passed implements `ICollection<T>`. In the first case, `List<T>` implements `ICollection<T>`, so `AddRange` can call `CopyTo` to do a bulk copy. In the second you're just passing in an arbitrary `IEnumerable<T>`, so it has to iterate over it in order to proceed.

Fundamentally you're doing something odd in the second case though. The simple answer is not to do that. I wouldn't expect the results to be guaranteed - it should be up to the implementation whether it eagerly iterates over the passed in sequence and *then* copies it, or whether it does it lazily. Either implementation will work fine for any *sane* sequence.

Comment: It's exactly what I ask about. Is it ok if my implementation always (!) performs eager iteration?

Comment: @voroninp: Yes, that's fine. Although it's a bit inefficent, if you're copying to an array. You could do the same test for `ICollection<T>` in your `AddRange` method, if you wanted.